# Set breakpoints in C++ debugger (vs code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The issue I'm having is that when I run "C++ run/debug active file" the the code executes but doesn't stop at the breakpoints I set. I don't know a lot about how debuggers work but I'm guessing the the debugger isn't listening to the correct process? Or why would this happen?

In all honesty, I've been struggling to get all my dependencies correct and in the process may have broke intended functionality so it could be that I set up the scripts in a way that breaks it's intended use.

`tasks.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "main.cc",
                "-o",
                "main",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-I/usr/local/include/cairomm-1.16",
                "-I/usr/local/lib/cairomm-1.16/include",
                "-I/usr/include/cairo",
                "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "-I/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "-I/usr/include/uuid",
                "-I/usr/include/freetype2",
                "-I/usr/include/libpng16",
                "-I/usr/include/sigc++-3.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-3.0/include",
                "-L/usr/local/lib",
                "-lcairomm-1.16",
                "-lcairo",
                "-lsigc-3.0",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-9",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-L/usr/local/lib",
                "-lcairomm-1.16",
                "-lcairo",
                "-lsigc-3.0"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

`launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "main.cc",
                "-o",
                "main",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-I/usr/local/include/cairomm-1.16",
                "-I/usr/local/lib/cairomm-1.16/include",
                "-I/usr/include/cairo",
                "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "-I/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "-I/usr/include/uuid",
                "-I/usr/include/freetype2",
                "-I/usr/include/libpng16",
                "-I/usr/include/sigc++-3.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-3.0/include",
                "-L/usr/local/lib",
                "-lcairomm-1.16",
                "-lcairo",
                "-lsigc-3.0",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-9",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-L/usr/local/lib",
                "-lcairomm-1.16",
                "-lcairo",
                "-lsigc-3.0"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

---

I reworked it and went slower this time. I don't have a launch file but

Here's tasks:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/usr/local/include/cairomm-1.16",
                "-I/usr/local/lib/cairomm-1.16/include",
                "-I/usr/include/cairo",
                "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "-I/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "-I/usr/include/uuid",
                "-I/usr/include/freetype2",
                "-I/usr/include/libpng16",
                "-I/usr/include/sigc++-3.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-3.0/include",
                "-L/usr/local/lib",
                "-lcairomm-1.16",
                "-lcairo",
                "-lsigc-3.0",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And here's c_cpp_properties

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/lib",
                "/usr/local/lib/cairomm-1.16/include",
                "/usr/local/include/cairomm-1.16",
                "/usr/include/sigc++-3.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-3.0/include",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/freetype2"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry, updated

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put it in the tags, should I put it in the title as well?

Comment: Funny how Microsoft managed to get something as simple and well understood as "building some C++ source with g++" so complicated and tied in to THEIR platform (VSC) that I am looking at this mess and go "nope, won't bother". :-D

Comment: @DevSolar haha yeah not a fan, I'm going through a new project and putting it together more slowly to make sure I understand each step and hopefully catch what I broke

Comment: @DevSolar yes, vscode is more of a glorified text editor than an ide, however with the right plugins a cmake project just works with no additional configuration. Other projects are simplified by not trying to build from within vs code and just using it to invoke an external build system

Comment: Have you checked the debug console for errors? Do the breakpoints come up as enabled when debugging?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I got it working now (made a separate project and went slower) Not sure how I goofed it up the first time but it's working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a lot of unnecessary code in your tasks.json , try this out I am successfully able to set breakpoints during debugging .

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: IDK if this is the right answer but I got it working and I'm grateful for your response! I'll post up with I ended up using on my question

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is right because I needed a lot of the options in order to get some dependencies to work and it looks like you went with just the ones in the directory

Comment: ya , I will try to edit it in a better way before posting the next answer , thanks for the suggestion!!